# Can Mathematica (or its extensions) do integration following Risch algorithm?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, implementation-details

I wonder whether there are option for indefinite integration in Mathematica that alow to choose the algorithm?

Is there an option to use this algorithm in Mathematica?

Comment: You should post the code for your Integrate/NIntegrate and explain why you think the result is disappointing

Comment: Mathematica uses the Risch algorithm for many indefinite integrals. But it is not something that can be altered by option settings.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I get. Open reduce. It does not evaluate the integral? Or are you using different version?

```
   int( x/sqrt(x^4+10*x^2-96*x-71),x);
```

[image]

Mathematica does evaluate it, yes, the result is large, but it does it:

```
   Integrate[x/Sqrt[x^4 + 10 x^2 - 96 x - 71], x]
```

[image]

But integration is tricky business. Here is a [report](http://12000.org/my_notes/ten_hard_integrals/index.htm) of the first 10 Charlwood's integrals, comparing 11 different CAS systems (Reduce among them) and you can see the final result there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Rubi. Seems like a nice package for when `Integrate` chokes or spits out an unwieldy expression.

Comment: This now works in closed form in 13 version. Not because of Risch, alas.

Answer (score 2):

[This notebook](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/Rubi4.3.zip) provides an alternative integration engine for Mathematica, claimed to outperform the standard one.

Comment: http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/

Comment: Really the results of Rubi 4.3 outperforms MMA 9. But loading the integrator could have been streamlined.

Comment: @PlatoManiac by "outperforms" I mean better results rather than "works faster"